# Independence of random variables and exponential distribution events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Suppose that the useful life of a certain brand of LEDs is randomly distributed, identically and independently, with the probability distribution function $F$. These LEDs are randomly selected, one at a time, and their useful life is measured. Let $N$ be the random variable that corresponds to the first LED that will last more than $s$ hours. Let $X_N$ be the useful life of said LED. Are $N$ y $X_N$ independent random variables? justify.

Actually the only thing I know is that the distribution function is independent, I can write it like this
$$
F_{X_1,X_2,...X_N}(x_1,x_2,...;x_N)=\prod_{i=1}^{N}F_{X_i}(x_i) \hspace{5mm}\forall i
$$
Also $N$ follows an exponential distribution (or so I understand), then $N \sim Exp(s)$

I do not know how to compare $N$ with $X_N$, but since I know that $X_N$ is the useful life of said LED, I understand that it refers to the expected value. Then one is a random variable $N$ and the other would be the value of a probability.

Thanks for the help. Well the doubt ends up being more conceptual

Comment: $X_N$ is not the expected value.  It says that the useful life is measured.  $X_N$ is the value determined by that measurement.  Think about this.  What happens to $N$ and $X_N$ if we increase $s$?

Comment: I have been reviewing the concepts more, and I understand that if $s$ increases, the random variable $N$ will take very high values, in the same way, $X_N$ will also do it. That is already reason enough for them not to be independent, since it would not be fulfilled that $F(X=x|Y=y)=F(X=x)$

Comment: But would that be a valid justification? It is that I do not see the mathematical justification, which I suppose, is the most important

Comment: I would think it's justification enough.  We don't know the distribution of any of the random variables, so I don't know how to calculate anything.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry to answer late, but really thanks for help

Comment: It was my pleasure